# I need to know about wallets in cryptocurrency, how do exchanges generate deposite address per user?

Tags: cryptography, wallet, cryptocurrency

In exchanges like Binance when a user wants to deposit coins in bitcoin or in other coins, per user receives a unique public key? Do they have to generate pair key private/public key for each user in each coin? Or there is a way that we can have many public key for a special private key and Binance had one private key and unlimited public key related to that?

If anybody have a good reference please let me know or give me description about this subject. thanks.

Comment: Most exchanges use hierarchically determined subkeys, or subaddresses and map them to a user account. Exchanges in my experience tend not to generate and hold a specific pub/priv key pair, per customer, per ccy. I have built these type of solutions in production for capital markets customers

Comment: This is off-topic here. SO is focused on programming questions. I think your best bet is [bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/). You may well get a bitcoin-specific answer there.

Comment: Note that BitCoin and Ethereum have narrowed their scopes. Please check their respective tutorials on what you can ask before posting on these sites.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes Thanks if you send me any specific tutorial for this challenge in my mind.

Comment: @James Reinstate Monica Polk Thanks I didn't know BSE .

Comment: @Woodstock Thanks, I'll research about "hierarchically determined subkeys"